# How to edit a bash alias in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, edit

I would like to edit this script and am not very familiar with the command:

alias phoneinfoga.py='python3 /opt/PhoneInfoga/phoneinfoga.py'

I have tried to nano it but nothing populates the screen when the terminal switches to nano mode.

Comment: "I have tried to nano it"- what did you try to nano?

Comment: @ToxicMonkey : And what is "nano mode"? In bash, I know that we can choose between emacs-mode and vi-mode for command line editing, but there is no such thing as a nano-mode. And if you don't like nano for editing your files, just use one of the many other text editors available.

Comment: And what is "this script"? If this text is in a file then edit that file. But the text you are displaying in the question is just a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gedit ~/.bashrc` and add the line.
Then type `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal to make your new settings active.
It would do the trick.

Comment: `reset` just redraws the screen. You might have to `source ~/.bashrc` (or `. ~/.bashrc`) to source the new alias.

Comment: `gedit` is an editor which requires a GUI and will only be installed on some platforms. More generally just edit the file with whichever editor you are familiar with. If you are not familiar with any editor, `nano` is fairly ubiquitous and considered reasonably user friendly (though I actually disagree).

Answer (score 1):

There is a special file in Ubuntu for users aliases `~/.bash_aliases` Here's mine for example.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_aliases 
#jboss
alias js='./krupd jboss.start'
alias jt='./krupd jboss.stop'
alias jk='./krupd jboss.kill'
alias jr='jt; js'

#editors
alias n='nano'
alias g='gedit'

#git
alias gc='git commit -am'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gbm='git checkout master'
alias gbd='git checkout dev'
alias gp='git push'
alias ga='git add'

#clear
alias cls='clear; ls'
alias ccls='cd; cls'

#utils
alias S="~/SCR/sshto"
alias fm='LANG=us free --si -h'
alias nst='netstat -tulpn'
alias psc='ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head'
alias psm='ps aux --sort=-pmem | head'
alias dumb='du -shx * | sort -rhk1'
alias sysupdate='sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get autoremove -y; sudo apt-get autoclean -y'

#cp with waiting animation
[[ -e ~/SCR/spiner ]] && { alias cp="~/SCR/spiner cp"; }

#fun
alias suco=sudo
```

Comment: I follow this pattern for every distro now... I just add `[[ -r "$HOME/.bash_aliases "]] && source "$HOME/.bash_aliases"` to my `~/.bash_profile`